# How check key in array?

Tags: php, arrays

Good day.

I have array:

```
$arg = array(12) { ["domain"]=> string(6) "7OXD.COM" ["nserver"]=> string(17) "ns2.fastpark.net." ["state"]=> string(31) "REGISTERED, DELEGATED, VERIFIED" ["person"]=> string(14) "Private Person" ["registrar"]=> string(12) "R01-REG-RIPN" ["admin-contact"]=> string(42) "https://partner.r01.ru/contact_admin.khtml" ["created"]=> string(10) "2010.02.17" ["paid-till"]=> string(10) "2014.02.17" ["free-date"]=> string(10) "2014.03.20" ["source"]=> string(3) "TCI" ["Last updated on 2013.09.04 01:26:34 MSK"]=> string(0) "" [""]=> string(0) "" }
```

How  check have array key **nserver** or no ?

P.S.: i use `if(in_array("nserver",$arg)){echo 'yes';}` but not worked...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Try this: if(in_array("nserver",array_keys($arg))){echo 'yes';}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), not `in_array()`.

```
if (array_key_exists("nserver", $arg)) {
  echo 'yes';
}
```

Or if you know `nserver` won't be `null`, you could simply use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset). But `array_key_exists()` clearly communicates intent.